# Identify possible probability identity

Tags: probability-theory

Consider the following expression,

$$ \frac{P(Z|X)P(Z|Y)}{P(Z)} \ ,$$

where $X,Y,Z$ are random events. The conditional probability of an event $A$ given $B$ is defined as

$$ P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)} \ . $$

Then, can one define something as $A=Z|X \cap Z|Y$ and $B=Z$, which would imply $A\subset B$ and independence of $Z|X$ and $Z|Y$, if these definitions are legitimate? There is the conditional independence of two events $A$ and $B$ given $C$, which is defined as

$$ P(A \cap B  \ |C )=P(A|C)P(B|C) \ .$$

Could this also be related to the above expression? Or any other identity?

Comment: There is no such thing as $Z|X$.

Comment: Thought so, then the conditional probability idea makes no sense.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy How about $X,Y,Z$ being random variables? If it is possible to take the probability of $Z|X$ or  $Z=z|X=x$, then why can't one define them as events or random variables respectively?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/112361/263915 for the first expression.